# How to drop row in polars-python

Tags: python, python-polars

How to add new feature like length of data frame & Drop rows value using indexing.
I want to a add a new column where I can count the no-of rows available in a data frame,
& using indexing drop rows value.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (df['col1'][i] == df['col2'][i]) and (df['col4'][i] == df['col3'][i]):
        pass
    elif (df['col1'][i] == df['col3'][i]) and (df['col4'][i] == df['col2'][i]): 
        df['col1'][i] = df['col2'][i]
        df['col4'][i] = df['col3'][i]
    else:
       df = df.drop(i)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Polars doesn't allow much mutation and favors pure data handling. Meaning that you create a new `DataFrame` instead of modifying an existing one.

So it helps to think of the data you want to keep instead of the row you want to remove.

Below I have written an example that keeps all data except for the 2nd row. Note that the `slice` will be the fastest of the two and will have zero data copy.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [True, False, None]
}).with_row_count("row_nr")

print(df)

# filter on condition
df_a = df.filter(pl.col("row_nr") != 1)

# stack two slices
df_b = df[:1].vstack(df[2:])

# or via explicit slice syntax
df_b = df.slice(0, 1).vstack(df.slice(2, -1))

assert df_a.frame_equal(df_b)

print(df_a)
```

### Outputs:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────┬─────┬───────┐
│ row_nr ┆ a   ┆ b     │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ u32    ┆ i64 ┆ bool  │
╞════════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 2   ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 3   ┆ null  │
└────────┴─────┴───────┘
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────┬─────┬──────┐
│ row_nr ┆ a   ┆ b    │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ u32    ┆ i64 ┆ bool │
╞════════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 0      ┆ 1   ┆ true │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 3   ┆ null │
└────────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Comment: It says `slice` is faster but do you mean *slice*? Since there's no method call for slice here. :)

Comment: [:3] is syntactic sugar for `slice(0, 3)`

Comment: Right. I was looking at your answer and trying to understand what part of the code you said was better, so hence the question.

Comment: I shall add an example with an explicit `slice` as well. :+1: